# Proper formatting of values in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, etl

I have values in my column in postgres and I need help to transform in properly as part of my etl

### Sample data

```
    Amount
$1,000.00
$3.000,00
$200.000,00
$1,234,567.40
```

as you can see the first and last row are properly formatted. This is what I have done so far

```
 SELECT
        amount,
        CAST(LEFT(amount, strpos(amount, '.')-1) || ',' || SUBSTRING(amount,(strpos(amount, '.')+1),3) || '.' || SUBSTRING(amount,(strpos(amount, ',')-1),2) AS varchar) AS Formattedstring1
        
    FROM AmountTAable
```

I am not getting the correct result like

```
  Amount
$1,000.00
$3,000.00
$200,000.00
$1,234,567.40
```

Please help with the correct format, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try the following:

```
select cast(Replace(Replace(Replace(Amount,',',''),'.',''),'$','')::decimal(18,2)/100 as money) as Amount
from t
```

[Example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=45409b5bf8b6bdc6c5716ba8ef30b4ae)